# How to estimate best fit for factors

Tags: regression, extrapolation

I have a table of data that looks like this:

| Target | R1 | R2 | R3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3.70 | 0.7863000000 | 0.8313000000 | 1.1019000000 |
| 3.40 | 0.8750000000 | 0.9000000000 | 0.9994000000 |
| 3.40 | 0.7719000000 | 0.9500000000 | 0.9994000000 |
| 3.40 | 0.8550000000 | 0.9019000000 | 1.0763000000 |
| 2.15 | 1.1019000000 | 0.8094000000 | 1.0969000000 |

The real table has about 4,000 values.

I would like to estimate `Target` based on the `R*` values.

There should be some algorithm that would come up with a "Best Fit" based on my samples such that I can estimate Target then I insert new values (R1, R2, R3) into the table.

I would suspect it would be something like this:

`Target = C1*R1 + C2*R2 + C3*R3 + D1*R1*R1 + D2*R2*R2 + D3*R3*R3`

That is, some algorithm will give me C1, C2, C3, D1, D2, D3 that will estimate future values.

Comment: This is a typical problem for a multidimensional function minimizing routine, where the function to minimize is the sum of the squared errors between the model values and the data.  Any numerical analysis text will have a chapter or more on this.  This may be a better fit for cross validated.se